# xss prevention for form post in jsp

Tags: jsp, security

We receive a url input from user in json  send in body of HTTP request. We store this in DB and later we use this url in `<form id="cxmlPost" action="<CALLBACKURL>" method="post">`  is url provided by user. We see that there is possibility of Stored XSS here. Need guidance on how to protect our Application from Stored XSS. What are the best practices to validate or sanitise the user input URL.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research i first validated the URL to see if it is valid url and utf-8 encoded it before posting any content on it . did the job for me